# Can I remove the language selector in the ubuntu menu bar?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

In the ubuntu menu bar (top right hand corner), there's an icon to select different keyboard layouts/languages:

[image]

I don't use any other keyboard layouts besides EN, so I don't need this. Is there any way to remove it? I tried searching for it but I'm not sure of the correct term for it. I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. Apparently I wasn't looking hard enough.

1. Click "Text Entry Settings"

   [image]
2. Then uncheck "Show current input source in the menu bar"

   [image]

Comment: This is only valid on Unity (by default up to 17.04), not on GNOME Shell, where you would need [an extension](https://github.com/ai/hide-keyboard-layout)